# Why can't you use RSpec's "let" method to set instance variables?

Tags: ruby, rspec

Given that `let` is a memoization technique, why can't it be used to initialize instance variables?  For example, why does the following succeed?

```
describe "let method" do
  let(:@bar) {1}
  it "does not define instance variables" do
    expect(@bar).to be_nil
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

While `let` is commonly spoken of as a mechanism to initialize *variables*, it in fact is a mechanism to define helper *methods*, as described in https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-6/docs/helper-methods/let-and-let and demonstrated by the following example, which passes:

```
describe "let method" do
  let!(:@bar) {1}
  it "defines helper methods" do
    expect(send(:@bar)).to eq(1)
  end
end
```